# Perl Net::DNS version 1.35 resolver query fails

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to test out the new version of cpan-Net-DNS (version 1.35) and it fails in the Net/DNS/Resolver/Base.pm file at line 987 with the following error.

```
***  FATAL PROGRAM ERROR!!  Unknown instance method 'size'
***  which the program has attempted to call for the object:
***
.   IN  OPT  ; no data
***
***  THIS IS A BUG IN THE CALLING SOFTWARE, which incorrectly assumes
***  that the object would be of a particular type.  The type of an
***  object should be checked before calling any of its methods.
***
Net::DNS::RR 1714 at Net/DNS/Resolver/Base.pm line 987.
    Net::DNS::Resolver::Base::_make_query_packet(Net::DNS::Resolver=HASH(0x55ebcfcd3d68), "example.com") called at Net/DNS/Resolver/Base.pm line 402
    Net::DNS::Resolver::Base::send(Net::DNS::Resolver=HASH(0x55ebcfcd3d68), "example.com") called at Net/DNS/Resolver/Base.pm line 374
```

Has anyone seen this before?

This was on linux version 5.15. I tried the same thing on linux version 5.10 and it works but I can't pin point as to why. Here is the snippet of code I am running. This is on perl5.26

```
use Test::Simple;
use Net::DNS;
my $resolver = new Net::DNS::Resolver();
my $packet = $resolver->query('example.com');
ok($packet->answersize > 0, "NET::DNS");
```

Comment: *"This was on linux version 5.15. I tried the same thing on linux version 5.10"* - whatever you mean with this: The linux kernel version - irrelevant, some linux distribution like RHEL, CentOS, ... - please specify. The really relevant thing though is the version of Net::DNS used, not the version of linux or the distribution.

Comment: Hi, sorry yes I meant the linux kernel version. This is a customized linux distribution of my employer which is built upon Ubuntu

Comment: Does the error really happen with `example.com` or  with another value you've entered? In the latter case - did you also try `example.com`?

Comment: Yes it does happen with example.com and any other URL I enter

Comment: So does DNS resolution work at all in this environment (linux kernel 5.15), i.e. have you tried [dig](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) or just `ping example.com` ? And if these work - is it only Net::DNS 1.35 or also older versions?

Comment: Yes I have tried dig, ping etc on both versions & this error happens on version 1.18, 1.31 and 1.35. These are the only versions I have tried so far

Comment: *"Yes I have tried dig, ping etc"* - and do they work on 5.15, i.e. show the expected IP address? Because - for me your code actually works with 5.15.

Comment: Interesting. Then its probably the way I am building the module & something is off in my make. Thanks for your help

Comment: Re "*I am trying to test out the new version of cpan-Net-DNS (version 1.35)*", Did you modify it? The call to `size` is found at [line 978](https://metacpan.org/release/NLNETLABS/Net-DNS-1.35/source/lib/Net/DNS/Resolver/Base.pm#L978), not [line 987](https://metacpan.org/release/NLNETLABS/Net-DNS-1.35/source/lib/Net/DNS/Resolver/Base.pm#L987) in version 1.35. We can't help you with software we know nothing about!

Comment: Apologies, I might have pasted the output of when I was testing version 1.18 in which the line number is 987

Comment: Rating my stupidity level at 10 I am gonna say that I didn't have the right PERLLIB set to the right path. In my defense the error wasn't very descriptive